# Trying to create a Status Menu app with Platypus.app

Tags: macos, perl, platypus

I'm trying to create a basic status menu app with [Platypus.app](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

I feel I'm almost there but I can't get there and it's been puzzling for a week now.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# If 0 arguments, we show menu
if (!scalar(@ARGV)) {
    print "MENUITEMICON|AppIcon.icns|~/Desktop\n";
    print "MENUITEMICON|/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AlertStopIcon.icns|~/Desktop/3DProjects\n";
    print "MENUITEMICON|https://sveinbjorn.org/images/andlat.png|~/Desktop/2DProjects\n";
    print "SUBMENU|Submenu|Item 1|Item 2|Item 3\n";
    
} else {
    # We get the menu title as an argument
    
    
    system("open  $ARGV[0]");
}
```

This works if I use the relative path as the menu name, but that doesn't look good. How do I use Open Desktop, Open 3DProjects etc as the menu and have it open the correct folder?

Also, is it possible to add an icon to the submenu items?

Comment: To clarify your question and allow us to try reproduce, please include details on how you created the app with platypus, see [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use Open Desktop, Open 3DProjects etc as the menu and have it open the correct folder?

Can you try save the absolute path in the script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @menu = (
    {
        icon => 'AppIcon.icns',
        path => '~/Desktop',
        text => 'Open Desktop'
    },
    {
        icon => '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AlertStopIcon.icns',
        path => '~/Desktop/2DProjects',
        text => 'Open 2DProjects'
    }
);

# If 0 arguments, we show menu
if (!scalar(@ARGV)) {
    for my $item (@menu) {
        print "MENUITEMICON|" . $item->{icon} . "|" . $item->{text} . "\n";
    }
}
else {
    # We get the menu title as an argument
    my $path;
    my $text = $ARGV[0];
    for my $item (@menu) {
        if ($item->{text} eq $text){
            $path = $item->{path};
            last;
        }
    }
    system("open $path");
}
```

Comment: Fixed one typo in the script