# Assigning icons to submenus in Platypus.app

Tags: perl, platypus

Continuing on with[Trying to create a Status Menu app with Platypus.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606126/trying-to-create-a-status-menu-app-with-platypus-app) I'm now stuck on trying to assign icons to the submenu items. I can't get the "MENUITEMICON" and "SUBMENU" commands to work together. I can't find anything on the web, but I'm not a coder so I'm probably looking in the wrong areas and using wrong search words.

code to add icons:

```
MENUITEMICON|my_bundled_file.png|Bundled file example\n
MENUITEMICON|/path/to/icon.png|Absolute path example\n
MENUITEMICON|https://sveinbjorn.org/images/andlat.png|Remote URL example\n
```

code to add submenu:

```
SUBMENU|Title|Item1|Item2|Item3\n
```

I tried things like below but it didn't work:

```
SUBMENU|MENUITEMICON|my_bundled_file.png|Title|Item1|Item2|Item3\n
```

How do I combine the two commands?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I checked the documentation, but it seems to be missing information about setting sub menu item icons, see for example this example: https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/blob/master/Examples/StatusMenuDemo.platypus. Maybe it is not supported yet?

Comment: Maybe you should add a feature request to the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/issues

Comment: I sent the developer an email a week or two ago and I still got no response...feature request might do it